# What am I riddle , can you see me?

Tags: riddle

You see me, I see you,

Scratch my back, I am dead,

You think, I have directional dyslexia,

But its not me, but its you who is suffering,

You might love me or hate, I am always your twin sibling,

Now you see me? What am I?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you:

> My reflection or mirror image?

You see me , I see you ,

> looking in the mirror

Scratch my back , I am dead ,

> scratch the back of a mirror and the glass becomes clear

You think , I have directional dyslexia,
But its not me , but its you who is suffering ,

> mirror writing

You might love me or hate , I am always your twin sibling ,

> your mirror images looks like you

Answer (score 2):

You see me , I see you ,

> Mirror!

Scratch my back , I am dead ,

> Scratch the metal behind the mirror and it no longer works!

You think , I have directional dyslexia,

> Written text looks reversed left-to-right and vice versa aka "mirror
>   image"!

But its not me , but its you who is suffering ,

> It's the beholder that suffers to read the text!

You might love me or hate , I am always your twin sibling ,

> I just look like *you* (aka *twin*)!

Now you see me ? What am I ?

> Mirror, again!!